# Using a database with Silverlight?

Tags: sql, database, silverlight, linq

For a school project we have to create a simple silverlight website where people can register themselves in a database and where the admins of the website can edit the website.

My biggest problem is that I have no clue on how to connect to a database, how to fetch data from it and how to put data in it.

I have found [the following tutorial](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/data-networking/network-services-%28soap,-rest-and-more%29/web-services-and-silverlight), but it is confusing to adjust it to my own database, because they tell you to "add" excisting code pages which are not compatible with my own Database.

The rest of the tutorials I can find on the internet are for Silverlight 2 or less but we have to use Silverlight 4.

Thank you,
Schoof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create a Silverlight enabled web service
- Write the same ADO .NET/LINQ database access code in the web service
- Reference the web service in silverlight
- Use the webservice objects for your CRUD operations

Comment: Thank you for answering me, but I have no idea how to do any of those steps. We have barely gotten an introduction to Silverlight in class and I don't really know a lot about it. My apologies.

Comment: Thank you Brian, but I posted a link to a tutorial at silverlight.net where they try to explain, but do this by throwing pages of code at you and not explaining what any of the code does.